# Can't query on DynamoDB records where attribute is null

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Can't get query on DynamoDB null attributes.
I have below query, I am getting `NameError: name 'true' is not defined`

```
const filter = {
    FilterExpression: 'id = :null',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':null': true,
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the type of null as well.

Try this :

```
const filter = {
  FilterExpression: 'id = :null',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':null': {BOOL: true}
  }
};
```